# WPF TargetInvocationException when trying to change textbox text in SelectionChanged method

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

So my code gives me a TargetInvocationException

[link to screenshot of exception details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T25z.png)

This is my code

```
public partial class MainWindow
    {
        Double totalPrice = 0;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void txtDiscount_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           Double newTotalPrice = 0;
           if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDiscount.Text))
           {
               newTotalPrice = totalPrice - Double.Parse(txtDiscount.Text);

           }
           txtFullAmount.Text = newTotalPrice.ToString();

        }
```

The last line is the one thats making it crash, Im trying to assign a textbox to change whenever a different textbox changes.

The funny part is that this works perfectly if I change the title instead

```
this.Title = newTotalPrice.ToString();
```

Edit: Also my original code works if used with a button instead.

Edit `<TextBox Background="#ecf0f1" IsReadOnly="True" Text="" Name="txtFullAmount" SelectionChanged="txtDiscount_SelectionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="505,511,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85"/>`

Comment: Can you also show the complete .cs and .xaml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you set a `SelectedIndex` in your XAML. In this case, the `SelectionChanged` event is raised before the window is completly initialized. Before the initialisation, the member variables for the controls are always `null`.

The easiest way is to check if the TextBox exists and return if it is `null`:

```
private void txtDiscount_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(txtFullAmount == null) return;
    //your code
}
```

The assignment to the `Title` works, because `this` exists already at this moment.

Comment: I understand but i still dont know how to fix it, this is my textbox ----<TextBox Background="#ecf0f1" IsReadOnly="True" Text="" Name="txtFullAmount" SelectionChanged="txtDiscount_SelectionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="505,511,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85"/>

Comment: if(txtFullAmount == null) return; fixed it all